# Problems with CUSTOM TEMPLATE in SILVERLIGHT

Tags: silverlight

I have problems with creating my own template from resource dictionary . It shows me exception : Error [Line : 0 Position : 0] . I can't find the error . Here is my source :

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:oktaCMS.Menu">   
    <!-- RIBBON PANEL TEMPLATE -->
    <Style x:Key="RibbonPanelTemplate" TargetType="local:RibbonPanel">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:RibbonPanel">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DefaultStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FFE2DFEF" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" CornerRadius="4">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="ContentArea" Margin="0,0,0,20" Background="Transparent"/>
                                <Border BorderBrush="#FFE2DFEF" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="20" CornerRadius="0,0,4,4" Background="#FFD1CDE6">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Can you show the XAML or code where you are trying to apply the template?

Comment: I am applying it in code behind :

Comment: How are you loading the XAML?  Are you getting the error at this stage, or when you actually apply the template?  More detail about what exactly you are doing would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are loading the XAML dynamically using XamlReader.Load(), then you probably need to qualify your "local" namespace with the full name of your assembly (not just the clr namespace).

E.g. change this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:oktaCMS.Menu"
```

to something like this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:oktaCMS.Menu;assembly=MyAssemblyName"
```